# Русские символы из массива PHP "криво" отображаются на странице

Tags: php, utf-8, charset

Есть сайт,  с выбором языков. Часть текста берется из базы данных (я поставил кодировку на подключение) и русский язык из бд отображается нормально.
Но ещё у меня есть файл `php`, который я подключаю  к странице на которой нужно отобразить текст из этого файла.
В файле,  в массиве содержатся некоторые слова на русском и английском языке и когда нужно отобразить русские слова он на странице они выглядят какими-то символами. 
Пытался ставить кодировку в этом файле так `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` но в таком случае слова из файла отображаются нормально,  а все остальные(из бд) знаками вопроса и прочим. 
Кодировка на соединении с бд: 

`$connection=mysqli_connect(server, name, pass, db_name);
$connection->set_charset("utf-8");`.

Опишу структуру: есть файл `lang.php` в котором содержится текст в таком виде:

```
$blog_single_arr = [
"no_art"  => [
    "no_art_title" => [
        "en" => "No Articles.",
        "ru" => "Нет статей."
    ],
    "no_art_text" => [
        "en" => "Sorry, but there are no articles on this category.",
        "ru" => "Извините, но статьи по этой категории отсутствуют"
    ]
];
```

Потом, я подключаю этот файл к файлу самой страницы и там, в зависимости от выбранного пользователем языка я вывожу текст таким образом:(`$current_lang` это либо 'en' либо 'ru')

`<?php echo $blog_single_arr['no_art']['no_art_title']["$current_lang"];?>`

То есть сам файл служит только ресурсом, с которого, при потребности я беру текст.
Подскажите,  как можно сделать так что бы русские слова из файла отображались нормально?

[image: Отображение текста из бд с заголовками]

[image: Отображение текста из файла без заголовков]

Comment: посмотрите кодировку самого файла (notepad++ умеет и показывать и конвертировать). Там вполне может быть 1251 кодировка.

Comment: @ArchDemon нет,  с кодировкой все в порядке там, только что проверил

Comment: Попробуйте поставить следующие заголовки `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');` и покажите какие у вас символы? Мне обычно этих заголовков за глаза хватает

Comment: @Walfter после вставки заголовков все так как я и писал, все что из бд выглядит как на первом скрине, а текст из файла отображается нормально. Второй скрин отображение текста из файла без заголовков(с бд без них все нормально отображает)

Comment: Utf-8 без BOM в файле кодировка?

Comment: @Solo_777 да, я даже перепроверял

Comment: Судя по скрину у Вас два слёта. Насколько помню первый utf-8 в исо стандарт а второй из utf-8 в cp1251. Вы не пробовали установить везде(в файлах и базе и заголовках) одну и туже кодировку?

Comment: Выставите в браузере жёстко кодировку utf-8 и посмотрите какие данные у вас криво отображаются: из базы или из файла.

Comment: @ArchDemon вы имеете ввиду этот тег  `<meta charset="utf-8">`? Если да, то с ним криво отображаются данные из файла. Если вы имеете ввиду кодировку в плане настроек браузера, то насколько я помню эту функцию вырезали в хроме.

Comment: Нет. Я имею ввиду кодировку в браузере. А что у нас кроме хрома браузеров больше не существует?

Comment: @ArchDemon все такие проверил,  и эту возможность вырезали из последних версий браузеров

Comment: Чудес не бывает. У судя по симптомам, у вас проблема всё же в БД. В самой БД другая кодировка таблиц (столбцов). Можете попробовать выполнить SQL запрос на изменение кодировки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решил, поменял кодировку в подключении к бд на `$connection->set_charset("utf8");` и поставил на отображаемом файле `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`
То есть получил одинаковую кодировку из бд и файла, а потом поставил нужную для всех данных.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

У тебя возле `utf=8` одной кавычки нет, может в этом проблема.

Comment: нет,  все так же, при написании этой строки в файле, слова из файла выглядят нормально,  а  те, что из бд - как на первом скрине

Comment: @МаксимБуяков у меня такое было. Если я не ошибаюсь, то скорее всего разные кодировки. У меня такое было около 2 месяцев назад, я работал с phpmyadmin + html файлом и у меня точно такие ромбики записывались в базу. Хорошенько подумай. Я точно не помню как решил этот вопрос.

Comment: Так в том то и дело что проблема то по сути не  в базе, я добавил ещё немного описания в вопрос.

Comment: @МаксимБуяков попробуй через SET names cp1251